# Getting [Unknown process name] CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. error while trying to reload the swipeMenuView

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

Initially i hit service to get data. after getting the data I setup the swipeMenuView(it is 3rd party library for swipeAction b/w VCs) So , 1st time its working fine but after I select Year from dropDown again I am hitting the service to get new data and reloading the swipeMenuView But nothing reloading on screen in Console I am getting this  [Unknown process name] CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix error i searched about it in internet and in stackoverflow but i didn't get proper answers. So , can anyone please get me out of this problem Please refer to my below code and let me know what is wrong. thanks in advance.

**Network call to get data**

```
    func getData(finYearID : Int = 3)
{
    guard Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() else {DispatchQueue.main.async {self.showAlert(message: NoInternet)};return}
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.showLoading(text: loading)
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

        OfficerNetworkCalls.shared.getFinancialYears()
            {[weak self](financialYears) in
                self?.finYears = financialYears.finYears
                //update ui for financial Year Button
                OfficerNetworkCalls.shared.getDistrictWiseData(finYearID: String(finYearID))
                    {[weak self] (districtData) in
                        self?.AllDistrictVC.districtData = districtData
                        //update ui for districts in dashboard
                        OfficerNetworkCalls.shared.getAgeWiseChartData(finYearID: String(finYearID))
                            {[weak self](ageWiseData) in
                                self?.AllGenderVC.ageData = ageWiseData
                                //update ui for ageWiseChart in dashboard
                                OfficerNetworkCalls.shared.getGenderWiseChartData(finYearID: String(finYearID))
                                    {[weak self](genderchartData) in
                                        //update ui for gender chart in dashboard
                                        self?.AllGenderVC.genderData = genderchartData
                                        OfficerNetworkCalls.shared.getBloodGroupWiseChartData(finYearID: String(finYearID))
                                            {[weak self](bloodGroupData) in
                                                //update ui for blood Group data in dashboard
                                                self?.AllBloodGroupVC.bloodGroupData = bloodGroupData
                                                OfficerNetworkCalls.shared.getGovtPvtWiseChartData(finYearID: String(finYearID))
                                                    {[weak self](gvtpvtdata) in
                                                        //update ui for govtPvt chart in dashboard

                                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                            self?.AllGovtPvtVC.govtPvtData = gvtpvtdata
                                                            //self?.removeChildVCs()
                                                            if self?.isSwipeAdded == true
                                                            {
                                                                self?.swipemenuView.reloadData()
                                                            }
                                                            else{
                                                                self?.swipeMenuSetup()
                                                           }
                                                            self?.hideLoading()
                                                        }
                                                }//End of gvtPvtSerivce Call

                                        }//End of bloodGroupDataService Call

                                }//End of GenderWiseSerice Call

                        }//End of AgeWiseSerice Call


                }//End of DistrictWiseSerice Call

        }//End of FinancialYearSerice Call


    }//End of Background thread black
}
```

> am i correct in hitting multiple serivices?

**Selct Button Action**

```
@IBAction func selectYearButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("select button action")
    let dropdown = DropDown()//DropDown is 3rd party library for dropdown action
    dropdown.dataSource = finYears.map{$0.finYear}
    dropdown.anchorView = sender
    dropdown.show()
    dropdown.selectionAction = {[unowned self](index : Int , item : String) in
            sender.setTitle(item, for: .normal)
        print(self.finYears[index])
         //hitting service to get newData based on finYear
        self.getData(finYearID: self.finYears[index].finYearID)
            dropdown.hide()

    }
}
```

**SwipeMenuSetup Method**

```
func swipeMenuSetup()
{
    isSwipeAdded = true
    swipemenuView.delegate = self
    swipemenuView.dataSource = self
    options.tabView.style = .segmented
    options.tabView.margin                          = 0.0
    options.tabView.additionView.underline.height = 2.0
    options.tabView.additionView.backgroundColor    = UIColor(named: ThemeConstant.bgColor.getTheme())!
    options.tabView.backgroundColor                 = UIColor.white
    options.tabView.itemView.textColor              = UIColor.darkGray
    options.tabView.itemView.selectedTextColor      = UIColor.black
    options.tabView.itemView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(12.0))
    options.tabView.height = 40
    options.tabView.isSafeAreaEnabled = false
    swipemenuView.reloadData(options: options)


}
```

Answer (score 6):

finally i found the problem. The problem is with the Charts(3rd Party library for Charts) I am using charts to display data. When We receive empty array of data i am getting this error but I don't know why I am getting this error